# Multiple WMI queries into a single Format-Table

Tags: powershell

I think what I'm needing help with is putting multiple WMI queries into a single table.

For example:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $server | Format-Table PSComputerName,DataWidth
```

That's fine, but I also need the OS Version on the same row. For that I have to inquire Win32_OperatingSystem and extract the Caption property. So how do I get the two separate WMI queries into the same table?

I've tried the following:

```
$os = gmi Win32_Processor -Computername $server
$cpu = gmi Win32_OperatingSystem -Computername $server
```

Then I can get the properties I want easily:

```
$os.PSComputerName,$cpu.Caption,$os.DataWidth
```

But from what I've read, Format-Table only accepts data from a single pipeline. It doesn't seem to know what to do with (variable).(property)

Ideally, I'd be able to run as the last cmdlet in the scriptblock:

```
Format-Table $os.PSComputername,$cpu.Caption,$os.DataWidth
```

but of course, Format-Table is always at the end of a line, never at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Calculated Property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for one of the objects and the normal pipeline for the other:

```
$os = gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -Computername $server
gwmi Win32_Processor -ComputerName $server | Format-Table @{name="ComputerName"; exp={$os.PSComputerName}},Caption,DataWidth
```

Comment: This is what I'd recommend. Alternatively you can merge everything into one large table, and I can help with that if this solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: That's close, @zdan. Close enough for me to blunder into the solution. Your answer grabs the Caption from the Win32_Processor, which isn't what I need. I inverted your answer (plus some trial-n-error) to yield this: `$cpu = gwmi Win32_Processor -ComputerName $server
gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server | Format-Table @{ name="ComputerName"; exp={ $cpu.PSComputerName}},Caption,@{name="DataWidth"; exp={$cpu.DataWidth}}`

Answer (score 0):

In case my previous edit wasn't clear:

$cpu = gwmi Win32_Processor -ComputerName $server

gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server | Format-Table @{ name="ComputerName"; exp={ $cpu.PSComputerName}},Caption,@{name="DataWidth"; exp={$cpu.DataWidth}}